# K disjointed paths with multiple destinations

Tags: algorithm

The Suurballe's algorithm is to find k disjoint paths of a source-destination pair, but now, I have the problem that the destination is not single. For example, I want to find k (K>=3) disjoint paths from node 'A' to node 'B','C','D', how to solve this problem?

BTW, from where I can get the codes (better Java) about the Suurballe's algorithm?(the simple version).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to minimize the total path length? Or is it ok to just find three edge disjoint path from A to B, C, D respectively in your example?

Comment: Yeah I need to minimize the total path length

Comment: I don't know Suurballe's algorithm, but can you do something like adding a dummy destination T and connect (B, T), (C, T), (D, T) and use the algorithm to find three edge disjoint (A, T) path?

Comment: That means these 3 nodes (B CＤ) are aggregated into a single node. If so, original links connected to node B and node C respectively will be connected to the new node at same time ?

Comment: I think it is not the same as merging (B, C, D) to a single node. It is like adding three edges(B, T), (C, T), (D, T) to the graph. So the new node T will not be connected to other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your network to a network that has a unique sink. In order to accomplish this you have to add one "dummy vertex" to your original network – we will refer to it as super-sink. In addition to this you have to add an edge from every ordinary target to the super-sink.

[Lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) (C++) provide implementation of common graph algorithms.